# Communication between 2 python script in which the first one is continuously running

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pipe

I have 2 python scripts. 
To make it simple

1st script :

It is a simple infinite while loop in which a variable 'x' is being increased by 1(This script is always running)

Now what I want a 2nd script, when I call this script it should give me the present value of x

I read about multiprocessing ,pipe and queue but was not able to implement it

**EDIT:**

I tried the socket solution and I am getting errors

**Client Side**

```
import serial
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys
import socket
s=socket.socket()
port=43470
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',port))
sertx = serial.Serial('COM4', 115200)

while 1:
    for i in range(4):
        msg = str(i+1)
        # print('sending: ',msg.encode())

        msgstat = 'A' + msg
        #print(msgstat)
        #print(type(msgstat))
        tx_t = time.time()

        sertx.write(msg.encode())
        tx_t=str(tx_t)
        s.send(tx_t.encode())
        s.close()
        time.sleep(0.001)
```

Error - File ".\tx.py", line 23, in 
    s.send(tx_t.encode())
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
PS C:\Users\ambuj\Documents\Python Scripts>

**Server**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket() 

port = 43470 # make this any random port

s.bind(('127.0.0.1', port))

s.listen(5) # put the socket into listen mode

while True:

    c, addr = s.accept()

    data = c.recv(1024).decode("utf-8") # This data is received from the client script
    print(data)

    c.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can surely achieve this thing using socket communication. Just create a server script like this which will listen to any incoming data to a specific port...

```
import socket

s = socket.socket() 

port = 43470 # make this any random port

s.bind(('127.0.0.1', port))

s.listen(5) # put the socket into listen mode

while True:

    c, addr = s.accept()

    data = c.recv(1024).decode("utf-8") # This data is received from the client script

    c.close()
```

Now in your client script, you have to connect to the socket that is binded in that port. Make a client script like this...

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()          
port = 43470 # Use the same port number here as you did in the server script.
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port)) 
s.send(b"This data will be received by the server!")
s.close()
```

You can do the reverse as well. So the server will be able to send the data to the client script. Its a two-way communication.

Remeber: This is just a simple demonstraction to make things work. In actual case, modification is much needed.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I implemented it, At the client side I receive one value then I get an error mentioned above